# How to compile ixgbe network drivers on other linux kernel version

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, archlinux

I am using linux kernel version 3.6.7. I want compile ixgbe network drivers on vesion 2.6.39.4. Please specify the procedure

Answer (score 0):

Install the `kernel-devel rpm for 2.6.39.4` and compile against the new kernel. In `Makefile` use the Kernel directory as 2.6.39.4. Usually located in `/usr/src/kernels/`

Comment: how to change kernel directory in Makefile